# MacOS Clipboard Set-Path equivalent

Tags: node.js, swift, windows, macos, clipboard

I'm looking for a feature like Set-Path (Windows) but for MacOS. The way Set-Path works in Windows is, in Powershell you do

```
SET-PATH C:\my\file\path.jpg
```

which will then copy said file to the clipboard.

Is there a similar command in MacOS? With my current use-case, I need to copy a file by using a reference path programmatically.

Note: I am not looking to copy the contents within the file, as it may be an arbitrary file type.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question right, what you're after is pbcopy and pbpaste.

Open a terminal and do:

`$ cat C:\my\file\path.jpg | pbcopy`

Now that file is in the clipboard.

To put it somewhere else, that is, to paste it, do:

`$ pbpaste > C:\my\file\path\somewhere\`

Comment: Close but not quite.While I am looking to programmatically copy a file, I then need that file to be able to be pasted by either right clicking and selecting the paste option or by using cmd + v. pbcopy allows me to copy the file and paste it with pbpaste, but not via the right clicking paste method I mentioned above. I hadn't tried pbcopy and then cmd+v yet.